# get what is between html tags

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I want to get the text between the html tags using HtmlAgilityPack, I know its kind of basic but I need to check and fully understands how the library works.

here is the simple code:

```
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HtmlWeb htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = htmlWeb.Load("http://192.168.1.177/");
        Console.WriteLine();// write the html 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

this my page content coming from remote sensors :

[image]

i want my output to be:

analog input 0 is 213
analog input 1 is 201
analog input 2 is 206
analog input 3 is 214
analog input 4 is 223
analog input 5 is 240

without the html and /html tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
htmlDocument.DocumentNode.InnerText
```

- `DocumentNode` represents the root node of the HTML document
- `InnerText` contains all text nodes within current `HtmlNode`, concatenated (notice that `DocumentNode` property is of type `HtmlNode`).

Comment: thanks @har07
cant I get rid of <!DOCTYPE HTML> ? using HtmlAgilityPack
or I should just use regular exp or any other method ?

Comment: @SabirMoglad one possible way : `doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("html").InnerText.Trim()`

Comment: `Trim()` was just to remove 'unnecessary' leading & trailing whitespace